# how can I have a remap canceled when I switch between file types?

Tags: vim, remap

I have edited my `.vim/after/ftplugin/html.vim` to include

```
inoremap . >
inoremap > .
```

The problem is that now when I switch between to my  `css` file the remap still holds. I could (probably) cancel all remaps automatically when I load the `css` file, but this will negate any remap in my `.vimrc` file too (I think). Is there a way to make the remap only hold for the `html` file?

Comment: Did my answer solve your Problem? If yes may you please accept the answer. Else please feel free to ask for further help.

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for a buffer-local map:

```
 inoremap <buffer> . >
```

Have a look here:
http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/11.html

Or enter `:h map-local` in your vim